# Download database table column fields as CSV in Zend Framwework

Tags: php, zend-framework

I want to download database table column fields as CSV in Zend Framework. Are there any ZF libraries for this?

There are other questions here on SO that addresses this specific subject, but none of them provide me enough detail. Could someone please describe in detail how to do it?

Comment: You should accept some answers to your previous questions.

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume you have a standard DbTable model for your table. Get the table information using the [info() method](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.table.html#zend.db.table.info)

```
//the following is pseudocode and not meant to be copied directly, intended to guide
public function indexAction() {
    $model = new Application_Model_DbTable_MyTable();
    //This returns an array of table info
    $info = $model->info();
    //prepare the data so each line can be saved
    $data = $info['name'] . ',' . $info['primary'];
    //then write each line to the database, I usually use a function from
    // a utility class or a protected function
    //I would normally build an array of the data I want saved and then
    //iterate over the array saving as I go.
    $save = $this->_writeToFile($filename, $data);
}

//the following function is not pseudocode
protected function _writeToFile($filename, $content) {
        // Let's make sure the file exists and is writable first.
        if (is_writable($filename)) {

            // In our example we're opening $filename in append mode.
            // The file pointer is at the bottom of the file hence
            // that's where $somecontent will go when we fwrite() it.
            if (!$handle = fopen($filename, 'a')) {
                echo "Cannot open file ($filename)";
                exit;
            }
            // Write $somecontent to our opened file.
            if (fwrite($handle, $content) === FALSE) {
                echo "Cannot write to file ($filename)";
                exit;
            }
            echo "Success, wrote ($content) to file ($filename) <br />";
            //close file
            fclose($handle);
        } else {
            echo "The file $filename is not writable";
        }
    }
```

Hope this points you in the right direction.